# sqlite text data type comparison not working

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite database with data type text, but when I do comparison its not working if I do it this way :

```
select * from scanned_dbs where db = 'cdd_db';
```

[image]

But if i change the query to:

```
select * from scanned_dbs where db like 'cdd_db';
```

It works. But as valex pointed out it will also match cddAdb, cddBdb, ...and so on, so this is not the right way.

One more method I found which is working is this:

```
select * from scanned_dbs where cast(db as varchar) = 'cdd_db';
```

So can any one tell me why this is working and not the first one which is direct comparison...

Comment: then what's the problem in using like? don't use = then.

Comment: I want to know why it doesnt work with first?

Comment: what do u mean by doesnt work? Does it give an error?

Comment: The query runs but doesnt returns result..

Comment: can u show us ur table data? Query runs but doesn't return result means you don't have any data that's exact 'cdd_db'.

Comment: What is the expected outcome for scanned_dbs.db column?

Comment: its just a string i was expecting..

Answer (score 3):

[Because](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) an underscore ("_") in the LIKE pattern matches any single character in the string.

So when you use `db = 'cdd_db'` the only `db` value that matches is exact `'cdd_db'`. But when you use the LIKE operator `db like 'cdd_db'` then "_" symbol is a pattern so `db` values that match: `cddAdb,cddBdb,cddcdb,cddddb,cdd1db, ....`

Comment: try escaping the underscore: SELECT * FROM scanned_dbs WHERE db = 'card\\_data';